# How to import model in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, import, 3d, processing, p5.js

I'm currently working on a project with using p5.js. Until now, I could display 3D primitives shapes like boxes, spheres or cylinders. I searched on the Internet and found that p5.js only accepts .obj files as models. So I tried with following The Coding Train's tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FUI7HEEz9B0), but the result isn't the same.

I still have tried to put the code from the tutorial which seemed logical to me, but I have an error on the console.
For information, I run my project on http-server and no more with simply run the index.html file.
Here is the code:

```
let bottle;

function preload() {
    bottle = loadModel('glass_bottle.obj');
}

function setup() { 
    pixelDensity(10.0);
    createCanvas(800, 600, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    noStroke();
    model(bottle);
}
```

If you want to test with .obj files, you have free models here: https://www.turbosquid.com/fr/3d-model/free/bottle/obj

If you know if we can put other model format on p5.js, please let me know how.

The error message I had is:

> Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at p5.js:63060

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your code looks fine.

What version of p5 are you using? There was a known issue with [importing complex models](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/2263). Essentially, the way they did it was recursive which explains the:

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

In a later patch they altered their approach and took the iterative route.

**What you can do:**

1. Check to see if you can import a simpler/smaller model, if you can, you're likely experiencing the same bug
2. Go to a newer version where [this fix](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/pull/2455) has been merged in.